# How to add custom css if variant id not available - Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

This is in product-form and the below code output product variant. I want to add a `if-else` condition to add another class on top of it.

```html
<label 
    for="option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.parentloop.index0 }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="SizeSwatch">{{ value }}
</label>
```

Comment: @sercan by adding - {% if variant.available % }

Comment: I don't know Shopify; I just edited it when I saw the post.